# What is a reliable Sinhala font that is larger than Iskoola Pota?

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts, language

I am using the standard Microsoft font for Sinhala, Iskoola Pota, when writing in a mixture of Sinhala and English. However, compared to the English text in Arial font, the Sinhala is tiny. I am looking for a font that is larger when set to ~11pt. There are lots of options available when you google 'Sinhala font' but a lot of the websites look quite dodgy so I am wary of downloading fonts from them. Can anyone recommend a reliable source for alternative Sinhala fonts?

[image: The Sinhala font looks much smaller than Arial]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of Iskoola Pota on your system? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @James I have attached it in the main question.

Comment: It could be argued that Arial is too big rather than Iskoola Pota is too small, e.g. if you use Calibri instead then the sizes are more similar.

Comment: Good point! Annoyingly my company style font is Arial but maybe I will just have to make all of the Sinhala text larger.